# vertical Scrollbar appearing in my practice project

Tags: html, css

I am trying to improve my css skills by practicing making and cloning various projects , I was practicing this nft project from frontendmentor and faced this problem , A vertical scrollbar always appear on my web page and I don't know why is this happening , I have tried changing the height of my main container from 50% to 33% but the problem remains the same , I am attaching the code for your reference

```css
@import url(https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Outfit);
:root {
  --Soft-blue: hsl(215, 51%, 70%);
  --Cyan: hsl(178, 100%, 50%);
  --Very-dark-blue1: hsl(217, 54%, 11%);
  --Very-dark-blue2: hsl(216, 50%, 16%);
  --Very-dark-blue3: hsl(215, 32%, 27%);
  --White: hsl(0, 0%, 100%)
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--Very-dark-blue1);
  color: var(--White);
  font-family: "Outfit", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container {
  width: 33%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 3em auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: var(--Very-dark-blue2);
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}

.nft {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.nft img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: 12%;
}

h3.title-nft {
  color: var(--White);
  padding: 0 1.5em;
}

p.info {
  color: var(--Soft-blue);
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 1.75em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding: 1.75em;
}

li.eth {
  color: var(--Cyan);
}

li.clock {
  color: var(--Soft-blue);
}

hr {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-color: var(--Very-dark-blue3);
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin: 2em;
}

.footer img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 3em;
  border: 2px solid var(--White);
  margin-right: 1.75em;
}

.footer p {
  color: var(--Soft-blue);
}

.footer span {
  color: var(--White);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <title>Frontend Mentor | NFT preview card component</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nft">
      <img src="images/image-equilibrium.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
      <h3 class="title-nft">Equilbirium #3429</h3>
      <p class="info">Our Equilibirum collection promotes balance and calm</p>
      <div class="side-details">
        <ul>
          <li class="eth">
            <img src="images/icon-ethereum.svg" /> 0.041 ETH
          </li>
          <li class="clock">
            <img src="images/icon-clock.svg" /> 3 Days Left
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="footer">
      <img src="images/image-avatar.png" />
      <p class="creator">
        Creation of <span class="wrapper">Jules Wyvern </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a vertical scroll bar until I shrink the viewport enough so one is needed. I'm on Edge/Windows10 laptop. What device/OS/browser are you testing on?

Comment: I think on Safari. I see the scroll bar

Comment: I am using chrome on macOS , but the scrollbar is still visible , Idk why , how do i Fix this , and why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer why, but container ignore height: 33%, and using 100% + border. This and create problem. You can try use 33vh.

Comment: its still not working , I dont know why

Comment: I mean change heights on 33vh class container. I tried in code inspector and it worked